# How to give a Facebook App Tab access to the fan page data without having users log in?

Tags: facebook, api, tabs

I wanted to build a fan page tab that would pull that page's photo albums. At first I thought I would need to build app with extended permissions to ask for "manage_pages" and "offline_access" so that the app can use my access as page owner to access page data.

However, random users that go to the tab will now be asked for permissions also, which I don't want.

What's best way to build a tab that can access fan page data via the api?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any fancy privacy settings for your page, you can just use the Graph API to pull all albums from the page - means creating a tab and link to a php file on your server where you do just this. Downside of this is that it's quite slow, but I can't tell whether the javascript sdk would be any faster (don't think so)

If you need some help pulling and printing them out, leave a comment!

Comment: How do I check the privacy settings for my page? I don't believe I have any set. I have already coded my page and I can see the photos/events fine as an admin, but as a regular user (non-fan, and fan) I can't see any of the data.

Comment: That's more something for superuser.com , but all you need to do is to go to the page logged in as admin and click on 'edit page' on the top right corner. you'll land straight in the permissions tab where you can set everything.